# Windows 8 Hyper-V network not working on host

Tags: networking, windows-8, hyper-v

I have carefully followed the instructions in the [first answer](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access/472854#472854), but I still can't get the network adapter to be shared with the host operating system. My symptoms appear to be identical to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/510082/windows-8-hyper-v-cant-bridge-wifi-connection?rq=1), but a reboot did not fix the issue. Networking works fine for my VMs, and it's connecting to the wireless network, but I cannot get access to the Internet from my host OS.

It appears that [this guy is having the same problem](https://superuser.com/questions/527896/no-network-connection-on-host-or-guest-simultaneously-with-client-hyper-v-wind), but he hasn't said anything for a few days.

Here is a screenshot of my virtual switch configuration when I have it turned on:
[image: Hyper-V virtual switch settings]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend against using a wireless connection with Hyper-V, as it can cause no end of issues when trying to connect to networks.

You could try changing your Hyper-V network to an Internal network:

[image]

This appears as a new virtual network adapter in your host:

[image]

Then depending on your needs, **either** enable Internet Connection Sharing on your wireless adapter:

[image]

**or** bridge the new internal adapter and your wireless one (ignore that this screenshot shows two virtual networks):

[image]

Comment: I'd set this up before, and forgotten about the internal network adapter/sharing option. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter".
But it seems that there is a bug. If you create an external network connection with this check mark set then only your guests have internet connection.
uncheck this feature, apply settings  and than redo.

Check > Apply > uncheck > Apply > Check > Apply.
I tried to get this working for several hours. Thanks microsoft for this bug.

Network bridging or sharing internet connection is a very bad idea and not the right solution.
It makes sense if you are in a private network at home with only one network adapter, but if you have more than one interface in a business environment then do it right, not with a workaround.

Comment: I can vouch for this fix, i tried everything, then reset it all, added an external switch, then unchecked, hit ok, then rechecked it and hit ok. THEN I added it to the vm network properties and everything worked. thanks steven for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to have outgoing connections, setting up internal network and NAT is the right way to go.

Sometimes in addition to simply creating Internal virtual switch and NAT using following commands (which works in most cases):

```
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "NAT-Switch" -SwitchType Internal
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.200.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (NAT-Switch)"
New-NetNAT -Name "NAT-Network" -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.200.0/24
```

it may be necessary to also review your ExternalAddresses on the newly configured NAT.
Checkout:

```
Get-NetNatExternalAddress
```

If you get loopback address or other internal non-routable addresses, removing them with following command allows NAT to route traffic through proper network adatper:

```
Remove-NetNatExternalAddress -ExternalAddressID <ID>
```

I hope it helps!